# I ran into a merge conflict. How do I abort the merge?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I used `git pull` and had a merge conflict:

```
unmerged:   some_file.txt

You are in the middle of a conflicted merge.
```

How do I abandon my changes to the file and keep only the pulled changes?

Comment: I realise this is a super-old question, but do you want to abort the **whole** merge, and leave the branch you were merging unmerged, or just ignore this one file as part of a larger merge, letting all the other files merge in as normal? To me, your title implies the former, your question body wants the latter. The answers do both, without making things clear.

Comment: I got similar case on commit saying that automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result: `[rejected] gh-pages -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward)`

Comment: Gwyn, it could be useful to select an accepted answer here. The top voted one is a bit less safe than some of the more up to date solutions, so I think it would help to highlight others over it :)

Comment: Wasn't it (as simple as) `git merge --abort`?

Answer (score 2760):

Since your `pull` was unsuccessful then `HEAD` (not `HEAD^`) is the last "valid" commit on your branch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

The other piece you want is to let their changes over-ride your changes.

Older versions of git allowed you to use the "theirs" merge strategy:

```
git pull --strategy=theirs remote_branch
```

But this has since been removed, as explained in [this message by Junio Hamano](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=121637513604413&w=2) (the Git maintainer).  As noted in [the link](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=121637513604413&w=2), instead you would do this:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin
```

Comment: Instead of doing a hard reset, you could bring it to a more granular level by doing:
    `git fetch origin`

-->

    `git reset origin (soft reset, your changes are still present)`

-->

    `git checkout file_to_use_their_version_of another_file (steamroll your own changes back to match the origin)`



I never use git pull any more.   Since in a fight between my latest code and the origin, the origin should always win, I always `git fetch` and `git rebase origin`.  This actually makes my merges and conflicts few and far between.

Comment: I agree.  I also like to fetch first, and then examine the upstream changes (`git log ..@{upstream}` or `git diff ..@{upstream}`).  After that, like you, I'll rebase my work.

Comment: In addition to that I recommend to run "git clean -f" if you still have some untracked files you want to clean.

Comment: instead of `git reset --hard origin`, `git branch -r` (pick the branch name), `git reset --hard remote/branch` worked for me.

Comment: As noted in a more recent answer, as of version 1.6.1, it is possible to use 'git reset --merge'

Comment: I used `git merge -X theirs remote_branch` instead of `git pull --strategy=theirs remote_branch` as `theirs` looks like an option of `recursive`

Comment: There is no strategy `theirs`.

Comment: @mlt, `theirs` is indeed an option of recursive, it doesn't exist as a strategy of it's own (in current git), per the docs.

Comment: `git merge --abort` is far preferable.

Comment: `git fetch origin` followed by `git reset --hard origin/master` did the trick. BTW I 'am using git version 2.13.6 (Apple Git-96)

Comment: @Kzqai I use `git pull --rebase` once I have locally committed (normally amending so I have 1 commit per feature, at least until I push) my changes.

Comment: I would like to note for the next poor soul who ends up in my situation that when `git merge --abort` did not work, these steps did.

Answer (score 2375):

If your git version is >= 1.6.1, you can use `git reset --merge`.

Also, as @Michael Johnson mentions, if your git version is >= 1.7.4, you can also use `git merge --abort`.

As always, make sure you have no uncommitted changes before you start a merge.

From the [git merge man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

`git merge --abort` is equivalent to `git reset --merge` when `MERGE_HEAD` is present.

`MERGE_HEAD` is present when a merge is in progress.

Also, regarding uncommitted changes when starting a merge:

If you have changes you don't want to commit before starting a merge, just `git stash` them  before the merge and `git stash pop` after finishing the merge or aborting it.

Comment: Interesting - but the manual scares me. When exactly is it appropriate to use? When would you have to specify the optional `<commit>`? #GitMoment :-o

Comment: You'd typically use this when you want to redo the merge from the start. I have never had to specify the optional commit myself, so the default (no optional <commit>) is just fine.

Comment: Even with uncommited changes git was able to restore the state before the merge. Nice!

Comment: Is `git merge --abort` just a synonym for `git reset --merge`? The name certainly makes more sense, but does it have the same functionality?

Comment: `git merge --abort` doesn't work with octopus merge conflict, only `git reset --merge` does work.

Answer (score 647):

```
git merge --abort
```

> Abort the current conflict resolution process, and try to reconstruct
>   the pre-merge state.
>
> If there were uncommitted worktree changes present when the merge
>   started, `git merge --abort` will in some cases be unable to
>   reconstruct these changes. It is therefore recommended to always
>   commit or stash your changes before running git merge.
>
> `git merge --abort` is equivalent to `git reset --merge` when
>   `MERGE_HEAD` is present.

http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: This has been available since git v1.7.4. It's an alias for git reset --merge.

Comment: This is not available if the merge conflict was caused by another command, e.g. `git stash pop`.

Answer (score 116):

I think it's `git reset` you need.

Beware that `git revert` means something very different to, say, `svn revert` - in Subversion the revert will discard your (uncommitted) changes, returning the file to the current version from the repository, whereas `git revert` "undoes" a commit.

`git reset` should do the equivalent of `svn revert`, that is, discard your unwanted changes.

Comment: to be clear: `git revert` does not undo _the commit_, it undo the _changes_ that that commit introduced. And it does that by creating a new commit with the opposite changes than the target commit.

Answer (score 94):

For git >= 1.6.1:

```
git merge --abort
```

For older versions of git, this will do the job:

```
git reset --merge
```

or

```
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 87):

You can either abort the merge step:

```
git merge --abort
```

else you can keep your changes (on which branch you are)

```
git checkout --ours file1 file2 ...
```

otherwise you can keep other branch changes

```
git checkout --theirs file1 file2 ...
```

Answer (score 79):

In this particular use case, you don't really want to abort the merge, just resolve the conflict in a particular way.

There is no particular need to reset and perform a merge with a different strategy, either. The conflicts have been correctly highlighted by git and the requirement to accept the other sides changes is only for this one file.

For an unmerged file in a conflict git makes available the common base, local and remote versions of the file in the index. (This is where they are read from for use in a 3-way diff tool by `git mergetool`.) You can use `git show` to view them.

```
# common base:
git show :1:_widget.html.erb

# 'ours'
git show :2:_widget.html.erb

# 'theirs'
git show :3:_widget.html.erb
```

The simplest way to resolve the conflict to use the remote version verbatim is:

```
git show :3:_widget.html.erb >_widget.html.erb
git add _widget.html.erb
```

Or, with git >= 1.6.1:

```
git checkout --theirs _widget.html.erb
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. doesn't this smack of a poor git user interface, though?

Comment: @Peter: I'm not convinced. The desired result is achievable with a few basic commands with simple options. What improvements would you suggest?

Comment: I think the `git 1.6.1` command makes a lot of sense, and is good. That's exactly what I would have wanted. I think the pre-1.6.1 solution is inelegant and requires knowledge about other parts of git that should be separated from the merge resolution process. But the new version is great!

Comment: Well, without commenting on whether it's "poor" or not, let me say that I would *never* have guessed that a syntax involving 'show' and `:1:`, `:2:`, and `:3:` was the way to recover the base and two "tip" files, but I am immensely glad to know of this technique, so: thank you very much!

Answer (score 60):

Comments suggest that `git reset --merge` is an alias for `git merge --abort`. It is worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that a `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

> git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge`, but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`. **They are not only old and new syntax for the same thing**.

Personally, I find `git reset --merge` much more powerful for scenarios similar to the described one, and failed merges in general.

Comment: what is here actually meant by "failed merge"? Merge with conflicts or something else? Or to rephrase it: when is MERGE_HEAD not present? My follow-up question is there to understand better use of "git reset --merge".

Comment: @Ewoks `git stash apply` caused a merge conflict for me but `git merge --abort` did not help while `git reset --merge` did.

Comment: Had to use this to resolve a failed merge, I had no MERGE_HEAD for some reason so git merge --abort didn't work.

Comment: Heads up to anyone else considering this: MERGE_HEAD is not present when your merge happened because of `stash pop`; and `reset --merge` will delete your untracked files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099267/1623757

Comment: What I needed after a failed merge from a tag to master...

Answer (score 33):

If you end up with merge conflict and doesn't have anything to commit, but still a merge error is being displayed. After applying all the below mentioned commands,

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull --strategy=theirs remote_branch
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin
```

Please remove

> ***.git\index.lock***

File [cut paste to some other location in case of recovery] and then enter any of below command depending on which version you want.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git reset --hard origin
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Error: `Could not find merge strategy 'theirs'.`

Answer (score 21):

An alternative, which preserves the state of the working copy is:

```
git stash
git merge --abort
git stash pop
```

I generally advise against this, because it is effectively like merging in Subversion as it throws away the branch relationships in the following commit.

Comment: I found this approach useful when I accidentally merged to a git-svn branch, which doesn't handle that nicely.  Squash merges or cherry picks are better when working with git-svn tracking branches.

In effect my solution turns a merge into a squash merge after the fact.

Comment: Best answer to the question

Comment: How would this be different to a soft reset? A soft reset also resets the repository to head but doesn't touch the working copy.

Comment: Yes, but does "git reset --soft someref" spring to mind when your goal is "How can I abort the merge?". How do you know what to use for someref? Hence "git merge --abort" which does the right thing and is obviously named which is refreshing for Git.

Answer (score 21):

Might not be what the OP wanted, but for me I tried to merge a stable branch to a feature branch and there were too many conflicts.
I didn't manage to reset the changes since the HEAD was changed by many commits, So the easy solution was to force checkout to a stable branch.
you can then checkout to the other branch and it will be as it was before the merge.

`git checkout -f master`

`git checkout side-branch`

Comment: `git checkout -f main` for the post-2020 copy-pasters.

Answer (score 18):

Since Git 1.6.1.3 [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) has been able to checkout from either side of a merge:

```
git checkout --theirs _widget.html.erb
```

Answer (score 7):

To *avoid* getting into this sort of trouble one can expand on the `git merge --abort` approach and create a **separate test branch *before* merging**.

**Case**: You have a topic branch, it wasn't merged because you got distracted/something came up/you know but it *is* (or was) ready.

Now **is it possible** to merge this into master?

Work in a ***test*** branch to estimate / find a solution, then abandon the test branch and apply the solution in the topic branch.

```sh
# Checkout the topic branch
git checkout topic-branch-1

# Create a _test_ branch on top of this
git checkout -b test

# Attempt to merge master
git merge master

# If it fails you can abandon the merge
git merge --abort
git checkout -
git branch -D test  # we don't care about this branch really...
```

Work on resolving the conflict.

```sh
# Checkout the topic branch
git checkout topic-branch-1

# Create a _test_ branch on top of this
git checkout -b test

# Attempt to merge master
git merge master

# resolve conflicts, run it through tests, etc
# then
git commit <conflict-resolving>

# You *could* now even create a separate test branch on top of master
# and see if you are able to merge
git checkout master
git checkout -b master-test
git merge test
```

Finally checkout the topic branch again, apply the fix from the test branch and continue with the PR.
Lastly delete the test and master-test.

Involved? Yes, but it won't mess with my topic or master branch until I'm good and ready.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following worked for me (revert a single file to pre-merge state):

```
git reset *currentBranchIntoWhichYouMerged* -- *fileToBeReset*
```