# How do I finish the merge after resolving my merge conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge

I've read the [Basic Branching and Merging](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) section of the Git Community Book.

So I follow it and create one branch: `experimental`.

Then I:

1. switch to experimental branch (git checkout experimental)
2. make a bunch of changes
3. commit it (git commit -a)
4. switch to master branch (git checkout master)
5. make some changes and commit there
6. switch back to experimental (git checkout experimental)
7. merge master change to experimental (git merge master)
8. there are some conflicts but after I resolve them, I did 'git add myfile'
9. And now i am stuck, I can't move back to master

when I do

```
 $ git checkout master
error: Entry 'res/layout/my_item.xml' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
```

and I did:

```
$ git rebase --abort
```

No rebase in progress?

and I did :

```
$  git add res/layout/socialhub_list_item.xml
$ git checkout master
error: Entry 'res/layout/my_item.xml' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
```

What can I do so that I can go back to my master branch?

Comment: After I fix the conflict, perform the add, and then attempt to perform the commit with `git commit gf2n.cpp -m "Hand merge gf2n.cpp due to conflicts"`, it results in ***`fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge.`***. And of course, *"Partial commits"* do not appear to be documented or discussed anywhere in the git man pages. Performing a `git merge` after the fix results in ***`Please, commit your changes before you can merge.`*** What a broken ass tool...

Comment: git commit with explicit paths is documented in the manpage in the DESCRIPTION" as "3. by listing files as arguments to the commit command, in which case the commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead record the current content of the listed files (which must already be known to Git);" and also under the '--only' option.  I'm pretty sure the merge message was written by someone who assumed you'd read how the commit command works, and could recognize the meaning of the word "partial" in that description, if not already then at least again and more carefully. @jww

Comment: So, why does that case study merit careful reading for comprehension, then, while the manpages don't?  @jww

Comment: Well, using git clearly requires better reading comprehension than you're prepared to acquire. I'm perhaps even more unsure that's a fault in git than you are sure it is.

Comment: With Git 2.12 (Q1 2017), you will soon simply do a `git merge --continue`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41369600/6309)

Answer (score 367, accepted):

When there is a conflict during a merge, you have to finish the merge commit manually. It sounds like you've done the first two steps, to edit the files that conflicted and then run `git add` on them to mark them as resolved. Finally, you need to actually commit the merge with `git commit`. At that point you will be able to switch branches again.

**Quick Tip**: You can use `git commit -am "your commit message"` to perform add and commit operations on tracked files simultaneously. (Credit: @vaheeds)

Comment: If you use "git gui &" to do the commit - you may not realize your branch state is no longer "merging".  Following up with a "git status" is helpful to ensure your branch status is correct.

Comment: Try `git commit -am "your commit message"` to perform add and commit simultaneously.

Comment: `git commit` does work. And it's best to use it to get the default merge commit message populated for you. I avoid `git commit -am" since it will override the message

Comment: Try `git push`.

Comment: I got this situation in below scenario -> I merged X branch with Y branch. Then i realised i did something wrong in branch Y, so i fixed that and then I "amend" my changes in Y branch. Because of amend git didn't create new commit. So when I merged X branch with updated Y branch, It gave conflict. BTW thanks for this answer.

Comment: 'git commit' does work, when from the command line and if there are no unstaged changes. As @Arijoon says, it gives the default commit message for a 'merge'.

Comment: I like this "try this, who knows..." attitude when fixing any git issues  Big fan

Answer (score 308):

> How do I finish the merge after resolving my merge conflicts?

With Git 2.12 (Q1 2017), you will have the more natural command:

```
git merge --continue
```

And if you don't want to edit the message when continuing/resuming the merge:

```
git merge --continue --no-edit
```

If `--no-edit` does not work, as [akseli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2101072/akseli) reported in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474097/how-do-i-finish-the-merge-after-resolving-my-merge-conflicts/41369600?noredirect=1#comment126215103_41369600), you can do:

```
# Linux
GIT_EDITOR=true git merge --continue

# Windows
cmd /V /C "set "GIT_EDITOR=true" && git merge --continue"
```

You can define an alias for those commands.

Meaning, as explained by [mgnobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1609345/mgnobody) in the comments:

> if you run merge and get conflicts, you only need to do `git add` after resolving conflicts.
> DO NOT do `git commit` after `git add`. Your `git merge --continue` will do that for you.
>
> So, in short:
>
> ```bash
> git merge develop 
> # address conflicts 
> git add <conflicted files> 
> git merge --continue;
> ```

---

See [commit c7d227d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7d227df5bf7fe9d5df98a55cd637bfaf38685ea) (15 Dec 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 042e290](https://github.com/git/git/commit/042e290da6aee0a9f21cd5890ccf231c266e177e), [commit c261a87](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c261a87e704679203510d48ff4db7bc7006b8a5a), [commit 367ff69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/367ff694281ce569edd8f6e444fc770f92f5d215) (14 Dec 2016) by [Chris Packham (`cpackham`)](https://github.com/cpackham).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 05f6e1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05f6e1be8cdae1ebedf3cf7b7a072a3b35f945b5), 27 Dec 2016)</sup>

See [2.12 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.17.1/Documentation/RelNotes/2.12.0.txt#L50).

> ### `merge`: add '`--continue`' option as a synonym for '`git commit`'

> Teach '`git merge`' the `--continue` option which allows 'continuing' a
> merge by completing it.
> The traditional way of completing a merge after resolving conflicts is to use '`git commit`'.
> Now with commands like '`git rebase`' and '`git cherry-pick`' having a '`--continue`' option adding such an option to '`git merge`' presents a consistent UI.

Comment: I was getting ready post a comment about how this was recently added in 2.12 in Q1 2017, but then I reread the first line of your answer. No wonder the option wasn't found for me on version 2.10!

Comment: I tried git merge --continue and Git Bash wasn't able to recognize that as a command. But what worked was git commit -m "Commit message"

Comment: @Mimi OK, but are you using a Git 2.12 or more?

Comment: @VonC you are correct, I am using an older version of Git!

Comment: It is convenient, but `merge` doesn't have `--no-edit` parameter for cases when I don't need editing commit message. `git commit --no-edit` works just fine

Comment: @HarrySmith `git rebase --continue` does not have a `--no-edit`. But `git merge` does: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---edit

Comment: `--no-edit` parameter seems not to work in Git 2.35.1: `fatal: --continue expects no arguments`

Comment: @akseli OK. I have added an alternative to `--no-edit`

Comment: I wanted to add this for future folks: if you run merge and get conflicts, you only need to do `git add` after resolving conflicts. DO NOT do `git commit` after `git add`. Your `git merge --continue` will do that for you. 

So, in short, `git merge develop; <address conflicts>; git add <conflicted files>; git merge --continue;`

Comment: @mgNobody Very good point, thank you for that feedback. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 28):

In case you ever get stuck during a merge/rebase you can always

```
git reset --hard
```

to restore your working to the state of the last commit. This will lose your changes from the working tree so if you had local modifications before the merge they will be gone after this—which is why it’s advisable to not start a merge when you have local modifications. :)

Comment: obligatory warning: `git reset --hard` throws away uncommitted changes

Comment: Why not just `git merge --abort`, which has no risk of loosing anything?

Answer (score 14):

The next steps after resolving the conflicts manually are:-

1. git add .
2. git status (this will show you which commands are necessary to continue automatic merge procedure)
3. [command git suggests, e.g. `git merge --continue`, `git cherry-pick --continue`, `git rebase --continue`]

Comment: There is no git merge --continue

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad This is incorrect. Zie git output below after conflict:- 

```error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 ADD: _type to styleguide
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Comment: There is rebase --continue, not merge --continue

Comment: `git merge --continue`, which is what I am trying to do, results in ***`error: unknown option 'continue'`***. I'm fairy certain your answer is wrong since the [`git-merge` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) does not list it. What version of Git are you using? I am using `git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`. I also tried with MacPorts `git version 2.9.3`.

Comment: I'll check this out. Perhaps was older syntax. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: With git 2.10 for a simple merge the command is plain old `git commit`

Comment: Then why did I just do a `git pull` with merge conflicts and then `git add .` after updating followed by `git merge --continue`.  Worked for me.

Comment: I confess, I've been away from development for some year now, but the documentation still says `git merge --continue` is valid. So I'm not sure why you guys are experiencing errors. Sorry.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 13):

Whenever You merge two branches using command `git merge brancha branchb` , There are two possibilities:

1. One branch (lets say brancha) can be reached by the other branch (lets say branchb) by following its commits history.In this case git simply fast-forward the head to point to the recent branch (in this case branchb).

   2.But if the two branches have diverged at some older point then git creates a new snapshot and add a new commit that points to it. So in case 
   there is no conflict between the branches you are merging, git smoothly creates a new commit.

> Run `git log` to see the commit after you have merged two non-conflicting branches.

Now coming back to the interesting case when there are merge conflicts between the merging branches. I quote this from the page https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

> Git hasn’t automatically created a new merge commit. It has paused the process while you resolve the conflict. If you want to see which files are unmerged at any point after a merge conflict, you can run `git status`

---

So in case there are merge conflicts, you need to resolve the conflict then add the changes you have made to the staging area using `git add filename` and then commit the changes by using the command `git commit`  which was  paused by git because of the conflict.I hope this explains your query. Also do visit the link above for a detailed understanding. In case of any query please comment below , I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 13):

Just `git commit` it.

Optionally `git abort` it:
[I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge)

To make life easier with on merges install kdiff3 and configure it as a mergetool. Instructions: http://doodkin.com/2016/05/29/git-merge-easy-github-this-branch-has-conflicts-that-must-be-resolved-use-the-command-line/

That page contains this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cc4xPp7Iuzo

Answer (score 3):

***Steps to resolve conflict:***

1. First 'checkout' to your branch in which you want to merge from the other
   branch(BRANCH_NAME_TO_BE_MERGED)

---

```
"git checkout "MAIN_BRANCH"
```

2. Then merge it with "MAIN_BRANCH" by using command:

"**git merge origin/BRANCH_NAME_TO_BE_MERGED**"

---

```
Auto-merging src/file1.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/file1.py
Auto-merging src/services/docker/filexyz.py
Auto-merging src/cache.py
Auto-merging src/props.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/props.py
Auto-merging src/app.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/app.py
Auto-merging file3
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file3
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Now you can see it is showing "CONFLICT (content)", to those file which is having "CONFLICT", **see your code and resolve them**

3. run **"git status"** => It will show you what are the files that you need to add (which you have resolved):

---

```
 Unmerged paths:
      (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file3
        both modified:   src/app.py
        both modified:   src/props.py
        both modified:   src/utils/file1.py
```

4. Once you have resolved all conflict, add each file one by one by using below git command

---

```
git add file3
git add src/app.py
git add src/props.py
git add src/utils/file1.py
```

5. **"git commit"**
   (add some message when you are going to commit, if not then it will open vi or vim editor where you need to press "esc:q!" then press "enter")
6. run again **"git status"**

---

```
 On branch MAIN_BRANCH
  Your branch is ahead of 'origin/MAIN_BRANCH' by 10 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

7.**"git push"**

Comment: If you don't get any conflict then after step 2, directly push to git by using step 7

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I want to make clear is that branch names are just an alias to a specific commit. a commit is what git works off, when you pull, push merge and so forth. Each commit has a unique id.

When you do $ git merge , what is actually happening is git tries to fast forward your current branch to to the commit the referenced branch is on (in other words both branch names point to the same commit.) This scenario is the easiest for git to deal, since there's no new commit. Think of master jumping onto the lilipad your branch is chilling on. It's possible to set the --no-ff flag, in which case git will create a new commit regardless of whether there were any code conflicts.

In a situation where there are code conflicts between the two branches you are trying to merge (usually two branches  whose commit history share a common commit in the past), the fast forward won't work. git may still be able to automatically merge the files, so long as the same line wasn't changed by both branches in a conflicting file. in this case, git will merge the conflicting files for you AND automatically commit them. You can preview how git did by doing $ git diff --cached. Or you can pass the --no-commit flag to the merge command, which will leave modified files in your index you'll need to add and commit. But you can $ git diff these files to review what the merge will change.

The third scenario is when there are conflicts git can't automatically resolve. In this case you'll need to manually merge them. In my opinion this is easiest to do with a merge took, like araxis merge or p4merge (free). Either way, you have to do each file one by one. If the merge ever seems to be stuck, use $ git merge --continue, to nudge it along. Git should tell you if it can't continue, and if so why not. If you feel you loused up the merge at some point, you can do $ git merge --abort, and any merging will undo and you can start over. When you're done, each file you merged will be a modified file that needs to be added and committed. You can verify where the files are with $ git status. If you haven't committed the merged files yet. You need to do that to complete the merge. You have to complete the merge or abort the merge before you can switch branches.

Answer (score 2):

A merge conflict occurs when two branches you're trying to merge both changed the same part of the same file. You can generate a list of conflicts with `git status`.

When the conflicted line is encountered, Git will edit the content of the affected files with visual indicators that mark both sides of the conflicting content.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
conflicted text from HEAD
=======
conflicted text from merging_branch
>>>>>>> merging_branch
```

When you fix your conflicted files and you are ready to merge, all you have to do is run `git add` and `git commit` to generate the merge commit. Once the commit was made ,`git push` the changes to the branch.

Reference article: [Git merge](https://kolosek.com/git-merge/).

Answer (score 2):

After all files have been added, the next step is a "**git commit**".

"git status" will suggest what to do: files yet to add are listed at the bottom, and once they are all done, it will suggest a commit at the top, where it explains the merge status of the current branch.

Answer (score 2):

It may be late. It is Happen because your git HEAD is not updated.
this commend would solve that `git reset HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option also, I tried stash and worked fine for me without any commit

After you resolve all conflicts,

-> git stash

-> git stash apply stash@{0}

worked fine, you can switch to another branch also after this.