# You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists)

Tags: git

I made a branch called 'f' and did a checkout to master. When I tried the `git pull` command I got this message:

```
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

When I try the `git status`, it gave me the following:

```
On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 13 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   app/assets/images/backward.png
#   modified:   app/assets/images/forward.png
#   new file:   app/assets/images/index_background.jpg
#   new file:   app/assets/images/loading.gif
#   modified:   app/assets/images/pause.png
#   modified:   app/assets/images/play.png
#   new file:   app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-bootstrap.js
#   new file:   app/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui-bootstrap.css
#   modified:   app/controllers/friends_controller.rb
#   modified:   app/controllers/plays_controller.rb
#   modified:   app/mailers/invite_friends_mailer.rb
#   modified:   app/mailers/send_plays_mailer.rb
#   modified:   app/mailers/shot_chart_mailer.rb
#   modified:   app/views/friends/show_plays.html.erb
#   modified:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
#   modified:   app/views/plays/_inbox_table.html.erb
#   modified:   app/views/plays/show.html.erb
#   modified:   app/views/welcome/contact_form.html.erb
#   modified:   app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
#   modified:   log/development.log
#   modified:   log/restclient.log
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/C1A/C00/sprockets%2Fb7901e0813446f810e560158a1a97066
#   modified:   tmp/cache/assets/C64/930/sprockets%2F65aa1510292214f4fd1342280d521e4c
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/C73/C40/sprockets%2F96912377b93498914dd04bc69fa98585
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/CA9/090/sprockets%2Fa71992733a432421e67e03ff1bd441d8
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/CCD/7E0/sprockets%2F47125c2ebd0e8b29b6511b7b961152a1
#   modified:   tmp/cache/assets/CD5/DD0/sprockets%2F59d317902de6e0f68689899259caff26
#   modified:   tmp/cache/assets/CE3/080/sprockets%2F5c3b516e854760f14eda2395c4ff2581
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/CED/B20/sprockets%2F423772fde44ab6f6f861639ee71444c4
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D0C/E10/sprockets%2F8d1f4b30c6be13017565fe1b697156ce
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D12/290/sprockets%2F93ae21f3cdd5e24444ae4651913fd875
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D13/FC0/sprockets%2F57aad34b9d3c9e225205237dac9b1999
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D1D/DE0/sprockets%2F5840ff4283f6545f472be8e10ce67bb8
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D23/BD0/sprockets%2F439d5dedcc8c54560881edb9f0456819
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D24/570/sprockets%2Fb449db428fc674796e18b7a419924afe
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D28/480/sprockets%2F9aeec798a04544e478806ffe57e66a51
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D3A/ED0/sprockets%2Fcd959cbf710b366c145747eb3c062bb4
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D3C/060/sprockets%2F363ac7c9208d3bb5d7047f11c159d7ce
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D48/D00/sprockets%2Fe23c97b8996e7b5567a3080c285aaccb
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D6A/900/sprockets%2Fa5cece9476b21aa4d5f46911ca96c450
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D6C/510/sprockets%2Fb086a020de3c258cb1c67dfc9c67d546
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/D70/F30/sprockets%2Facf9a6348722adf1ee7abbb695603078
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DA3/4A0/sprockets%2F69c26d0a9ca8ce383e20897cefe05aa4
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DA7/2F0/sprockets%2F61da396fb86c5ecd844a2d83ac759b4b
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DB9/C80/sprockets%2F876fbfb9685b2b8ea476fa3c67ae498b
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DBD/7A0/sprockets%2F3640ea84a1dfaf6f91a01d1d6fbe223d
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DC1/8D0/sprockets%2Fe5ee1f1cfba2144ec00b1dcd6773e691
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DCC/E60/sprockets%2Fd6a95f601456c93ff9a1bb70dea3dfc0
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/DF1/130/sprockets%2Fcda4825bb42c91e2d1f1ea7b2b958bda
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/E23/DE0/sprockets%2Fb1acc25c28cd1fabafbec99d169163d3
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/E23/FD0/sprockets%2Fea3dbcd1f341008ef8be67b1ccc5a9c5
#   modified:   tmp/cache/assets/E4E/AD0/sprockets%2Fb930f45cfe7c6a8d0efcada3013cc4bc
#   new file:   tmp/cache/assets/E63/7D0/sprockets%2F77de495a665c3ebcb47befecd07baae6
#   modified:   tmp/pids/server.pid
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Coachbase/
#   log/development.log.orig
#   log/restclient.log.orig
```

What should I do?

Comment: my issue was that after resolving conflicts, there were not changes to commit, so I had to  `git commit --no-edit` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189488/6908282)

Answer (score 3001, accepted):

The problem is your previous pull failed to merge automatically and went to conflict state. And the conflict wasn't resolved properly before the next pull.

1. Undo the merge and pull again.

   To undo a merge:

   `git merge --abort`  [Since git version 1.7.4]

   `git reset --merge`  [prior git versions]
2. Resolve the conflict.
3. **Don't forget to add and commit the merge.**
4. `git pull` now should work fine.

Comment: I tried and gave me conflict in files(when pull)

Auto-merging app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Auto-merging log/development.log
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in log/development.log
Auto-merging log/restclient.log
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in log/restclient.log
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

I fixed the local files specified, and then I tried 'git pull'

Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.

Comment: @AnkitSuri, After fixing the conflicts, did you stage them and commit?

Comment: I tried it and it help me to get on flow again. After revert back I did try "git mergetool". It directly associate with merging tool.

Comment: Does not work: ``[env]$ git merge --abort
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.``

Comment: @user1429980: Which version of GIT you are using? did you try `git reset --merge`

Comment: @KarthikBose, it actually did end up working.  Since I was working over SSH, I had to start a new session and do a ``git status``.

Comment: @KarthikBose How do you add and commit a merge, since the files that were merged are already added? I get as response only the untracked files and on commit that I have nothing to commit

Comment: @chefarov After you resolve the conflict, the file needs to be staged. Execute "git add <filename> to stage the file. Then "git commit" to commit your merge. You got nothing to commit, after resolve the conflict?? It cud be because you chose local version of the file. Use git gui to commit empty merge.

Comment: Thank you very much, `git merge --abort` does the trick.
I wasn't able to re-merge after reset all files and this resolved my problem.

Comment: after `git merge --abort` I had to do `git pull` again to have a conflict to respond to. Then when I resolved using `Current Change`, VS Code told me there was no change and would not let me commit to complete the merge. So I did everything over again choosing the alternate resolve.

Comment: @cyrf alternatively, after aborting the merge, you should have undo last commit and then stash all changes, after stash you need to pull the latest code and then apply latest stash, by doing those all, then you need to resolve the merge conflicts and it should've worked.

Comment: `git commit` After relying on VSCode for git operations for some time, I totally forgot how to do the step 3. All I had to do was just commit without options. `git status` was showing nothing to commit but this command brought me to the editor to modify the merge message.

Answer (score 151):

If you are sure that you already resolved all merge conflicts:

```
rm -rf .git/MERGE*
```

And the error will disappear.

Comment: if you remove MERGE_HEAD, won't the resulting commit only have one parent so you won't have the history of the merged branch?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat in my case I'm temporarily merging in multiple PRs that haven't been accepted yet.  I don't plan to commit those merges on the feature branch, I just need them during development.

Comment: I had already resolved my conflicts and was still getting this error. So the command worked for me.

Comment: This saved me from a nasty merge conflict loop.

Comment: Failed for me: `fatal: pathspec '.git/MERGE*' did not match any files`

Comment: @Mojtaba, you were probably not at the root of your project.

Answer (score 110):

I think it's worth mentioning that there are numerous scenarios in which the message `You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists)` could occur, because many people have probably arrived at this page after searching for said message. The resolution will depend on how you got there.

`git status` is always a useful starting point.

If you've already merged the contents to your satisfaction and are still getting this message, it could be as simple as doing

```
git add file
git commit
```

But again, it really depends on the situation. It's a good idea to understand the basics before attempting anything (same link Terence posted):
[Git - Basic Merge Conflicts](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts)

Comment: Thank you for asking this, for those of us with the simpler type of problem.  "Git status" was what a newbie like me needed, to be reminded that the last step of fixing a conflicted merge was the simple command "git commit".

Comment: This has been really helpful, after checking, I discovered that I needed to add a file I modified unknowingly.

Answer (score 102):

I think this is the right way (this can delete local changes) :

```
git merge --abort

git fetch --all
```

Then, you have two options:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

OR If you are on some other branch:

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

Comment: only git merge --abort worked itself && git pull then

Comment: git reset --hard origin/<branch_name> worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Those commands delete all your local changes. We don't need that!

Answer (score 76):

Abort did not work for me.  So I had to `continue` and this is what worked for me:

```sh
git merge --continue
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, but I would love to know how my branch got into this state.

Comment: @AlexDresko, it could be because there was no` diff `between your branch and what you are trying to merge with after resolving the conflicts.

Comment: This works for me. I did `merge --abort` and `reset --merge` but still couldn't pull

Comment: I always get this error and still, end up looking up this answer. Always works for me

Comment: Only one that worked for me as well! Thanks @Aakash.

Answer (score 22):

Try

```sh
git reset --hard origin/trunk
```

'trunk' is the branch that I am trying to get to.

I don't know how or why this works. It had something to do with some commit I made which was forcing my pull requests to do a merge.

Comment: This worked in combination with above answers for me

Answer (score 16):

Commit merge changes solved my problem:

```sh
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Answer (score 14):

```
git merge --abort
```

This code fixed my problem.

Answer (score 13):

I resolved conflicts and also committed but still getting this error message on `git push`

> All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
> (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

I did these steps to resolve error:

```sh
rm -rf .git/MERGE*
git pull origin branch_name 
git push origin branch_name
```

Comment: What does the `push` at the end accomplish?

Answer (score 11):

Just run this command for aborting the conflict:

```
git merge --abort
```

After that, you can pull your project:

```
git pull origin YOUR_BRANCH
```

> Tested git version 2.25.1

Answer (score 10):

Git commit with add flag solved my problem:

```
$ git commit -am "commit message"
```

Answer (score 7):

Run `git status` and it will tell you what to do.

For example, in my case it was the message:
`All conflicts fixed but you are still merging. (use "git commit" to conclude merge)`

Indeed, running `git commit` solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing any temporary file. Like just remove any space or add space and then commit and push that file.

> git add 'temporary_change_file'
>
> git commit -m "git issue resolving"
>
> git push origin develop

And then try git pull,

> git pull origin develop

Hope this might help you.

Comment: This was the only thing that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I got this issue when I had two commits with same messages. What fixed my issue is,

```
git add.
git commit -m "New commit message"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had a cherry pick that produce a number of Merge Conflicts, so I decide to not complete the cherry pick.  I discarded all my changes.  Doing so put me into a state where I received the following error:

> You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists

To fix the issue I performed the following git command which fixed the problem.

```sh
git cherry-pick --abort
```

Answer (score 4):

Blockquote

If you're trying to pull from another branch into your branch. If you're seeing this error.

First, you should try doing git commit and then pull another branch into yours.

1. "git add . "
2. git commit
3. Then do git pull from the required branch.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `git merge --continue` with git version 2.12 and above to continue your merging after resolved the conflict. Can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474097/how-do-i-finish-the-merge-after-resolving-my-merge-conflicts/41369600#41369600)

Comment: This is right now, IMO, the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Best approach is to undo the merge and perform the merge again. Often you get the order of things messed up. Try and fix the conflicts and get yourself into a mess.

So undo do it and merge again.

Make sure that you have the appropriate diff tools setup for your environment. I am on a mac and use DIFFMERGE. I think DIFFMERGE is available for all environments. Instructions are here: [Install DIFF Merge on a MAC](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/08/install-diffmerge-git-mac-os-x/)

I have this helpful resolving my conflicts: [Git Basic-Merge-Conflicts](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts)

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure there are no conflicts before proceeding.

Check if there is no ***MERGE_MSG.**** file in your .git folder.

I knew there are no conflicts and somehow I´ve got 2 of those (one **.swp* second **.swo*) and deleting them (try maybe to cut+paste them to some different directory just in case) helped to handle the error and merge successfully.

Answer (score 1):

first,use `git pull` to merge repository save your change.then retype `git commit -m "your commit"`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the conflict and then do a commit with -a option.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This message is shown when you are in the middle of a merge. These steps worked for me to **finish the merge**:

1. stage files with the resolved conflicts,
2. commit, you may need to create an empty commit.

And you are done, now it should be possible to pull again.

Answer (score 0):

For those using SourceTree and don’t wanna jump to the terminal to hit and try these commands.
Just commit with any message without any changes and it will be resolved.

Answer (score -12):

This worked for me:

```
git log
`git reset --hard <089810b5be5e907ad9e3b01f>`
git pull
git status
```

Comment: First of all, this will delete all working directory changes.
Also the hardcoded version is not helpful, perhaps something like HEAD^ is better.

Comment: @Plus1 This is exactly what I need - remove my wrong local commits and apply changes with respect to the changed source code. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It caused a problem in my case