# How to check if git merge really did a merge in a multi-repo bash script

Tags: bash, git, github, merge, git-merge

So I am making a script that fetches the latest tag from the main remote repository and merges it into my local repos with my custom changes, for about 10-20 repos, in a single script. The merge part looks something like this:

```
git fetch -q https://android.googlesource.com/platform/$REPO_PATH $TAG
git merge -q --no-ff FETCH_HEAD
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "$REPO_PATH merged succesfully"
else
    echo -e "\n$REPO_PATH has merge conflict(s)\n"
fi
```

The point of this is that I want to know which all commits merged succesfully (and needs a push to my custom git). But sometimes the repos are already up to date (i.e. a new tag in the remote repo without any new commits), and in that case the "merged succesfully" message shows even though nothing has really been merged.

I only want to know which all repos underwent a merge and needs pushing to my git, and also want to know which all have merge conflicts (this works fine in my script though). All I have noticed is that when git does a real merge, it opens up nano asking for the commit message. But I have no idea how to detect merges using that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can suppress the commit message during a merge. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189488/989920

Comment: no, thats not the point. please read the last para

Comment: That is why I commented, not answered. Why does it matter which merged properly? If it's up-to-date a push won't do anything anyway.

Comment: no, as I mentioned, this script deals with over 10 repos and I dont wanna cd into each of them and do a git push to check whether I need to push it or not

Comment: Why bother checking? Just push in the repos which didn't fail merging (not "up-to-date").

Comment: in that case I wouldnt have asked the question here, I know that I can check myself

Comment: If a git repo is in a merge (due to conflicts) there will be an `index.lock` file in the `.git` folder. If the merge doesn't need to happen ("already up-to-date"), then push anyway as it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you start the merge, store the hash of the current branch head:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Then check it again after the merge command runs, if they are the same, the merge was unable to complete.

You can determine the status by checking the status code as well:

```
  | Match      | No Match                    |
  --------------------------------------------
0 | Up to Date | Merged                      |
  --------------------------------------------
1 | Conflict   | Something is horribly wrong |
  --------------------------------------------
```

Comment: but how do I use it to check whether a merge was needed ?

Comment: @Adithya You'll need to use both the status code and the hash comparison, truth table added

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for! BTW you meant "able to complete" right haha ?

Comment: @Adithya unable to complete is correct. if the merge completes, a commit was made and the HEAD will have changed.

Comment: Another command to check this up-to-date status: `git merge-base --is-ancestor <source branch name> <target branch name> && echo "merged" || echo "to be done"` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70389345/3894752).