# Error in pull/push in sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am tring to pull in source tree but getting error and the same for push. The error messages are attached . Any idea how to sold this problem
thanks[image][image]

Comment: Read the errors, and if you don't understand what they're trying to tell you, put them into your favorite web search engine. Both problems have been asked about and solved before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646107/you-have-not-concluded-your-merge-merge-head-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have not concluded your merge (MERGE\_HEAD exists)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646107/you-have-not-concluded-your-merge-merge-head-exists)

Comment: @Ramaq, it would be nice if you at least accepted the provided answer if it helped you. That's how this site works

Answer (score 0):

Well, just as the messages tell you.

You cannot push as there are commits on master you don't have in your to-be-pushed branch unless you force the push and thus throw away the commits in the remote.

And you cannot pull as you are still in the middle of a merge and you cannot start a second merge while merging. Either abort or finish the previous merge to be able to continue.