# git merging problems while pulling

Tags: git, merge, pull

i have these errors while pulling in Git

error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.

amd  my name in the git command line appears like that  (master|MER                                  GING)

Comment: Assuming you want to continue with the merge:

Search your IDE for <<<< or >>>> and make sure all merge conflicts are resolved. Once your code looks correct, commit all files (`git add -A`), then commit (`git commit -m '[commit message here]'`). Then you should be good to proceed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have not concluded your merge (MERGE\_HEAD exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646107/you-have-not-concluded-your-merge-merge-head-exists)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Undo merge and pull again
 To undo:

```
git reset --merge
```

Then resolve the conflicts and make sure to add and commit the merge

Comment: what do you mean please by resolve the conflicts which command should i enter ?

Comment: This article might help you https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/