# If I commit to a branch then I pull from another branch onto mine, are the changes I first committed saved?

Tags: git, branch, commit, atlassian-sourcetree, pull

I have pulled onto my branch before but I would like to get an update and pull again but it's giving me this error

```
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists)
```

and suggesting that I should commit my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You have not concluded your merge (MERGE\_HEAD exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646107/you-have-not-concluded-your-merge-merge-head-exists)

Answer (score 2):

That happened because your first pull probably got you some conflicts. Check them by `git status` and fix.

So, to finalize the previous pull, you have to issue the command `git merge --continue`.

Instead, if you want to abort the failed merge, issue the command `git merge --abort`.

Is this you case?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your remote branch has been updated and the file you are working on also updated. When you pull the update it go to conflict state (your local changes conflicted with the update)

There is some effort you could do, but i suggest you to stash your local changes then try to pull the update again. After you successfully pull the update, you can apply stash to add local change you stashed before.

Answer (score 1):

You have some changes locally and when you pull code if some files has been modified by both, you will have to solve the conflicts between your editing and the remote update.
When all the conflicts are solved, you can `git merge --continue`, and check the status of the files using `git status`.
After that, if you need, you can pull again.