# Git merge: Re-check conflict resolution in files before commit

Tags: git-merge

I am using git. I want to merge files from branch `test` to my `master`. I did `git merge --no-ff test`. Now `git status` shows

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   new file:   a.txt
#   modified:   b.txt
#   renamed:    c.txt
#   deleted:    d.txt
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both added:         e.txt
#   both modified:      f.txt
#   both modified:      g.txt
#   deleted by us:      h.txt
#   deleted by them:    i.txt
```

Now I proceeded by `git mergetool`. I am using meld as my merge tool. Everything is fine till now. I resolved conflicts only on `e.txt`, `f.txt` and `g.txt`. Files `h.txt` and `i.txt` are not resolved yet. So haven't commited anything yet. Now I thought I have done some mistakes. I want to revisit what I have done so far. I want to have a re-look at `e.txt`, `f.txt` and `g.txt`.

How can I do it?

I tried to rerun `git mergetool`. But it doesn't show `e.txt`, `f.txt` and `g.txt`. It starts with `h.txt` and `i.txt`. :-(

For simplifying the situation I have given this txt files as an example. But actually I am trying to merge more than 500 files and more than 100 is with conflicts!

Please suggest.

Comment: If you don't have `mergetool.keepBackup` set to false, then you'd have backups (*.orig files) created by `git` upon merging.

Comment: The problem I see is, `git mergetool` automatically stages files for commit after I save file and quit meld. Those files are no more found in `Unmerged paths:` section of `git status`. I found `git checkout -m <file>` helps getting a file back to `Unmerged paths:` section of `git status`, when it is marked as `both modified:`. So that I can re run `git mergetool` on it. Similarly, how to revert back conflict resolution of files marked as `both added:`, `deleted by us:`, `deleted by them:` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting [the conflict resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409744/6309) is indeed:

```
git checkout -m FILE
```

> Similarly, how to revert back conflict resolution of files marked as both added:, deleted by us:, deleted by them

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785581/6309):

You can get contents of file with conflict markers using git checkout --conflict=merge -- file, but if you have cleaned up index by using git add file (or if GUI did that for you) it wouldn't work.

> There is **[`git update-index --unresolve`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---unresolve)**, but it is hacky, and does not work very reliably.
>   I think the state it restores would be not enough for git-mergetool.

(That was in 2010: it could work better in 2018)

> You would probably have to redo merge, or use [`git update-index --cacheinfo`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_cacheinfo_or_info_only) to manually set stages version.