# Merge two forks in Git?

Tags: git, merge, github, fork

I am a beginner to Git and only use Git Bash for basic things. I mostly commit/push/whatever else inside my IDE or with TortoiseGit. I'm trying to do something rather like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326894/git-how-to-merge-branches), I think :. (bear with me here, I'm not sure if I'm using proper terminology...)

So here's the situation: There's a main branch on Github. (let's say it's at github.com/branchadmin/info.git). If someone wants to improve the code of the main branch, they create a fork and push their changes. If a developer of the main branch likes the changes that a user made, they push to the main fork. That's great and all, but what if the developer also changes something else? That leaves the user's repo out of date, and I haven't found a way to "merge" it. (correct terminology? idk)

Without having to delete the fork and start a new one in order to stay up-to-date, how could the user do such a "merge?"

Thanks to all in advance :)

Comment: OK thanks everyone. Does anyone have any experience with Eclipse (Java IDE) and EGit (the plugin)? Looking through it's documentation I'm taken to multiple places, all of which don't work :\

Answer (score 3):

That's a "pull" from "upstream". Github documents it well here: http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Comment: OK, that seems simple... now to find out how to do it in an IDE :\

Answer (score 0):

[Basic Branching and Merging](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html)

After you merged a branch, don't forget that these changes are local and you still need to `push` them to the github.