# How to undo a git merge with conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I am on branch `mybranch1`. `mybranch2` is forked from `mybranch1` and changes were made in `mybranch2`.

Then, while on `mybranch1`, I have done `git merge --no-commit mybranch2`
It shows there were conflicts while merging.

Now I want to discard everything (the `merge` command) so that `mybranch1` is back to what it was before.
I have no idea how do I go about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge)

Answer (score 1697):

Latest Git:

```
git merge --abort
```

This attempts to reset your working copy to whatever state it was in before the merge. That means that it should restore any uncommitted changes from before the merge, although it cannot always do so reliably. Generally you shouldn't merge with uncommitted changes anyway.

Prior to version 1.7.4:

```
git reset --merge
```

This is older syntax but does the same as the above.

Prior to version 1.6.2:

```
git reset --hard
```

which removes all uncommitted changes, including the uncommitted merge. Sometimes this behaviour is useful even in newer versions of Git that support the above commands.

Comment: But for older versions of git this is the way to use

Comment: Sometimes you still need to use `git reset --merge` even in more recent versions. I've had `git merge --abort` error out (making no changes) where `git reset --merge` succeeds (and does the right thing) in git 2.2.1.

Comment: I found I needed to do `git merge --abort` followed by `git reset --merge` when having automerge conflict from popping my stash.

Comment: usually `git merge --abort` works for me, however I found myself in a situation where I checked out in a detached HEAD state, and one of my files had a "both modified" state. I wanted to discard everything and get back to a branch, I had to `git reset --hard`, `git merge --abort` told me there was no merge to abort, (MERGE_HEAD missing).

Comment: Sometimes `git merge --abort` isn't able to bring you back your previous state, and in that case the "older syntax" `git reset --hard` does the trick.

Comment: Got message "fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing)."

Answer (score 160):

Actually, it is worth noticing that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort # is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge` but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`, **so they are not only old and new syntax for the same thing**.

Personally I find `git reset --merge` much more useful in everyday work.

Comment: Thank you, this info was very helpful. I had a merge that started with `git stash apply` on a wrong branch, and `git merge --abort` did nothing (no `MERGE_HEAD`), while `git reset --merge` did the trick.

Comment: I've seen about 10 people saying `git merge --abort` is the new command for `git reset --merge` and I ran into the same issue as @geomaster this was super helpful thanks!

Comment: Tried this after a `git checkout --merge` which resulted in conflicts, ended up losing data. git docs say it will keep worktree files which differ from the index, which it does, but for any conflicted file, you get the checkout version, and the worktree version is completely lost.

Answer (score 114):

Assuming you are using the latest git,

```
git merge --abort
```

Comment: Ok this doesn't work with 1.7.0.7 :( . got to use reset --hard with it

Answer (score 69):

If using latest Git,

```
git merge --abort
```

else this will do the job in older git versions

```
git reset --merge
```

or

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: For me, with `git` version `2.31.1`, that was released later than this comment so I consider it "latest", only `git reset --hard` worked, and the rest didn't.

Answer (score 9):

There are two things you can do first undo merge by command

```
git merge --abort
```

or

you can go to your previous commit state temporarily by command

```
git checkout 0d1d7fc32
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mentioned this before, if you get this error

```bash
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

when trying the above methods you can try adding the files (staging them) and then instead of committing just do `git stash` you can use the `-m` flag and give it a tag so you know if you do by chance need to recover that last state you can find the stash with `git stash list`.

For me, `git reset --merge` and `git merge --abort` failed with above error.

Comment: I found this as well. I had to use `git reset --hard` to undo the failed merge.

Answer (score -1):

**Sourcetree**

If you not commit your merge, then just double click on another branch (=checkout) and when sourcetree ask you about discarding all changes then agree