# git how to merge many folder-conflicts quickly?

Tags: git

[image]

There are tons of folder-conflicts on my current work. I can merge one by one by clicking "Take Theirs" or "Take Ours". But it's too tiresome and wasting of time.

Do you have any good method? [Using Git bash or Git GUI is OK.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820559/10921202 Does this solution fine to you?

Comment: @dunajski, you means "git checkout --ours Readme.md", I checkout those folders one by one with "--ours"?

Comment: @dunajski, PS, I got those conflicts not by checkout, but "git stash pop" 

Comment: --ours , refers to files on branch that you checkout. But do you need those changes in stash? If not stash them again by `git stash` and then merge. If you need them you have to commit this changes before. Use `git stash --list` to check what's in your stash.

Comment: If you commited all your changes before using `git stash pop` you can type `git reset --hard` and this will back your work to this latest commit.

Comment: Perhaps show a part of `git status`. I think this is really clear about what you really have.