# Abort a Git Merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I am working on a project using Git as the VCS. I got a branch `xyz` cut from the mainline branch of master. After working for a while, I committed my code and took a pull of the branch mainline.

The pull was fine. I then merged the code with master. After the merge, there were problems in certain files. I have not committed the code after merging. Can someone please guide as to how I can abort this merge and bring my branch where I am working currently to the state where it was before I merged it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Can't you just restore the previous commit of the branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo a git merge with conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741407/how-to-undo-a-git-merge-with-conflicts)

Comment: Note that in Git, `revert` is the name of a command that creates a *new commit* reverting the changes in a previous commit, so that is probably not the word you are looking for here. I have [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to clarify.

Answer (score 627, accepted):

as long as you did not commit you can type

```
git merge --abort
```

just as the command line suggested.

Comment: I got this message when trying this:  `error: Entry 'MyFile.java' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.`

Comment: @Ahmad git does not start a merge with uncommitted changes (of already tracked files) in place. git cannot protect what it doesn't know.

Comment: yeah you are i learnt it by losing my code. here is detail of my problem , how i fell in problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474092/how-to-undo-the-git-abort

Comment: @SMBiggs When you have a merge conflict you resolved, but added unstaged local changes, it's somewhat odd to see a "**Cannot merge.**" message when you really want to abort the merge. However staging (i.e.: `add`) the unstaged changes and *then* `git merge -abert` woks (git 2.26.2).

Answer (score 41):

If you do "git status" while having a merge conflict, the first thing git shows you is how to abort the merge.

[image: output of git status while having a merge conflict]

Comment: Nice, this suggested me to `git reset HEAD <file>` which effectively removed the "merge" collapsable from the git extension source control => then I could either resolve the conflicts or just revert my changes in the GIT extension list :)

Answer (score 14):

Truth be told there are many, many resources explaining how to do this already out on the web:

[Git: how to reverse-merge a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809484/git-how-to-reverse-merge-a-commit)

[Git: how to reverse-merge a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809484/git-how-to-reverse-merge-a-commit/41920088)

[Undoing Merges](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503132847/https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html), from Git's blog (retrieved from archive.org's Wayback Machine)

So I guess I'll just summarize some of these:

1. `git revert <merge commit hash>`
   This creates an extra "revert" commit saying you undid a merge
2. `git reset --hard <commit hash *before* the merge>`
   This reset history to before you did the merge. If you have commits after the merge you will need to `cherry-pick` them on to afterwards.

But honestly [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503132847/https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) guide here is better than anything I can explain, with diagrams! :)

Comment: The link is gone.  Sigh.

Comment: @ScottBiggs I think they moved it to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_undoing_merges. Denis, if you read this, can you check? And if it's really the same, can you please update the link in your answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VScode then you can open the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and type:

> Git: Abort Merge