# How to undo the git --abort

Tags: git, git-merge, conflict, abort

Is it possible to undo the git abort. Scenario is that I was merging two branches when run command **git merge** its shows an error message you have uncommitted changes, therefor I run **git commit** now message appears "fatal error there is a merge conflict between, abort the operations to resolve the issue", so I run the command **git merge --abort**.
After this i lost my local code changes too. Is there any solution to undo abort or get my local code back.

Comment: Are the changes you've lost part of the branch you were trying to merge or separate changes?

Answer (score 4):

Undoing the abort is basically redoing the merge.

So, rerun the `git merge` to restart, solve the conflicts using `git mergetool` and finally run `git commit` to finalise the merge.

If you don't know how to use `git mergetool`, here is a guide about it: https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately if you didn't commit your changes in between the moment the failed merge started and the `--abort`, they haven't been saved anywhere.

You'll have to not only redo your merge but also these changes (though it might be a good idea to do so separately).

Comment: But how i could  do that ,  I only want my local changes back

Comment: @Ahmad What you lost in only what you did between the last commit before the merge and now. I know this can sound grim, but unless your IDE stored anything of your local changes, as hinted at by Ganesa, not much hope here.

Comment: @Ahmad if you're using an IDE like [Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-88.htm) or [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) there is a option called local history for every single file (usefull for few files).

Answer (score 3):

The straight answer is **NO** if you looking around git since there won't record for your uncommitted and deleted local changes but you can check your IDE and check that is there anything you can get from local history.

Comment: yeah i am looking for a git command solution because I also lost the code locally

Comment: Sorry, my friend, We don't have an option in git.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, if you ran `--abort` using some git client, check your git stash with `git stash list`, chances are the client stashed all changes before resetting your working tree.