# Easiest way to make local branch = origin branch

Tags: git, github

I pulled changes, and merged conflicts by accident.

The result: I have a bunch of local files with `>>>>>>>>>>>>>HEAD>>>>>>>>`, etc.

What is the easiest way to delete my local 'master' branch and 're-clone' the origin 'master' branch back to my repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aborting a merge in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/aborting-a-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BE WARNED: This will cancel all modifications you have made that are not on origin branch

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

`git reset` reverts your working copy, `--hard` option is to tell that you really want to forget everything. This has the exactly same effect than re-cloning from the origin repository.

Comment: if then I do `$ git pull origin master` it is unable to pull the clean copy: I still get the conflict alerts.

Comment: it must have something to do with rewritten history on the remote; do `git fetch origin` then `git reset`