# git reset HEAD before checking merge changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset

What does happen if i do a git merge from another branch, some conflicts happen, the merge does not get commited, and **then** i do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

can i do the merge again? or will git believe that the merge is already done?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/aborting-a-merge-in-git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your working copy will be reset to the state at HEAD, and no merge will be done. the working copy+index is at the same state is if you never had run `git merge`.

You can redo the same merge afterwards.