# Git merge mistake

Tags: git

I have made an mistake when merging with git. I have a master branch and another branch called mars.

The master branch contains very old code and I do not want to work with it. However, when I tried to get the latest code of mars, I did:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master       <------ This is a mistake as I should use "git merge origin/mars"
```

The last command failed with a merge failure and asked me to fix the conflict. I fixed the conflict and did

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

I think this should drop whatever I just manually solved confliction.

But I am not sure whether I have merged something from master to mars mistakenly. If so, the mars branch is contaminated.

Is there anyway I can confirm my local mars is not merged with anything from master? (it is not contanimated).

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aborting a merge in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/aborting-a-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 3):

You can revert to previous commit, ignoring any changes:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

where HEAD is the last commit in your current branch.

If you want to get remote mars branch

```
git reset --hard origin/mars
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't commit anything. I just did the "git merge origin/master" on the mars branch. I guess this will merge remote master into my local mars branch. Which is wrong. I just want to verify my local branch is still the same with remote mars.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is lost in git, and as long as you have not pushed anything, you can safely do a lot of commit graph surgery.

Check the logs (or use `gitk --all`) to find out what the branch pointers are and used to be. Then, if need be, change them to what they used to be with `git branch -f <branchname> <commit>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether there are differences at all (while being on `mars`):

```
git diff origin/mars
```

If there are differences, you'll notice them.

If there are differences or to ensure that your local `mars` branch is absolutely identical to a remote `mars` branch, do

```
git reset --hard origin/mars
```

**Careful! This will throw away any local changes to `mars` and makes it absolutely identical to `origin/mars`.**

Answer (score 0):

In git, when you try to merge and there is a conflict, it doesn't create a commit. This means that any changes that come up as a result of `git status` are changes you don't want. Verify that the last commit is the one that you want with `git log`.

If `git status` yields a result, override your changed files with the latest checkout by doing `git checkout *`. This assumes you are already on the mars branch.

If no output from `git status`, continue with your `git merge origin/mars` command as originally intended.