# resolve merge conflict github - use specific branch

Tags: github

I have two branches, develop and master. I push all my new work into develop and when done I need to merge it into master. I ran git merge --no-ff develop when in the master branch, but now I have a lot of merge conflicts. Is there a quick way to resolve these so I always use the develop version, instead of having to open each file and resolving them that way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a merge you don't want to go forward with right now, the first thing to do would be to abort that merge with `git merge --abort`

Then if you want to merge your 'develop' branch into checked out branch 'master' while always taking changes from 'develop' where conflicts arise, the way to do that is with `git merge -X theirs develop` where `master` is checked out already.

See:

[Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours)

and: [I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge)

for reference.

Comment: thanks, but git merge --abort gave me an error is that right? says a file canntot merge and fatal: could not reset index file to revision "HEAD"

Comment: That's not what I would expect. Is your git version < 1.7.4? In that case `git reset --merge` will perform a roughly analogous operation. The checked out branch is still in a merge conflicted state, right?