# git-rollback old branch after pull

Tags: git

I have pull the branch from remote to local.It's need to merge all conflict file.But I do not want to fix conflict and want to rollback my last commits to get my workflow back.If you have any idea for that please give me.

Comment: Would really appreciate a fast help .Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git reset --hard` to reset your branch to a known commit. If I understand you correctly, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to reverse changes by merge. If you want to reset to a particular commit, you can use `git log` to see commits and their hashes, then reset to the particular commit using `git reset --hard COMMIT_HASH`.

For more detailed explanation, I advice you to follow the [Atlassian tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset/).

**P.S**: Hard resetting will discard any uncommitted changed without warning, please stash or commit them, if they are important.

Comment: I have using git reset function .I run that git reset --hard COMMIT_HASH.Thank you very much Shubham.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not finished the merge (with `git commit`), you can abort the merge with `git merge --abort`.