# Revert all local files to old state Git

Tags: git, netbeans

I was working on a project and I need to upload all the project files to a Git repository.

The problem is that one of my mates mistakenly pushed all of jis git repository to my local work so I didn't lose my local work but my all files now have things like:

`<<<<<<< HEAD`

and

`=======`

and

`>>>>>>> b44bd41e433d8b387531c78c93bba88810ef8db3`

Now my local project has stopped working. I am developing my project in NetBeans.

Is there a way to fix this all from NetBeans or git etc? I am exactly not sure and am now stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge)

Comment: You probably pulled in his changes, and this caused a local merge with the above conflicts. You can either abort the merge (see the above link) to get back to your previous state, or you can try to resolve the conflicts (which you will have to do at one point). See here for details on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git