# Git Merge Branches Conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

I tried to Merge a Branch let's say branch-good into Master branch as branch-good is the one upto date with changes so whilst on branch-good I did following

```
git merge --strategy=ours master   
git checkout master
git merge branch-good
```

Now after I made my last commit i changed two files that i forgot to commit before performing above task. This has cause merge conflict and now i'm not able to got back to the branch-good so i can add those files to my last commit as git gives me Cannot save the current index or You need to resolve your current index first errors. How to get out of this ?

Comment: Possible dupe: [I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/101752/1426891)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix those merge conflicts. First, run `git status`to see exactly the errors and what files have them. Then, see here: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/ and fix those conflicts on the files that `git status` showed.
After resolving the conflicts, you can continue working.

Comment: that's exactly what i did and it's all resolved now. Thanks :))