# Android Studio keeps pulling the same items and does not push

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control

I have a problem in pulling item from my repository.
I commit with vcs my changes, then pull the modified items and then I would like to push my changes. The problem is that when I pulled the first time, android studio notified that 2 items were changed; then I've tried to push, and it told me that the push of current branch was rejected and that remotes changes need to be merged. I then chose merge, but an error in merging appeared and it couldn't push anything ("fatal:You have not concluded your merge(MERGE_HEAD exists)").
I've tried several times to pull again and it pulls always the same 2 items (when, after the first time, it had to tell me that no items were pulled since I've already pulled them).
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you do not need the information now but I'll respond because it is here -

From what I can see, when you first pulled the changes there were merge conflicts (that is, the merge was not completed).

So, when you pull again without resolving the conflicts the same error will show up again and again.

You will have to abort the merge using [I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge) and then perform the merge again(once the merge is completed you can continue with the other pull operations).