# Git: How to discard the merging conflicts with a commit

Tags: git, git-merge

Now I'm in a merging state. I want to discard all changes, to back to the state that before the merging, **and when I do the merge again, it says "Already up-to-date".** Is there a nice way to do it?

My attempt:
`git reset --hard head` 
but when I do the merge again, still conflict.
what I have to do is manually revert all changes by hand and do a empty commit, very tedious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I ran into a merge conflict. How can I abort the merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101752/i-ran-into-a-merge-conflict-how-can-i-abort-the-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you want to do a merge but, for every conflict, fallback to the version in the original branch instead of the one you are merging with.

If that's the case, tou can try using `-Xours`

```
git merge -Xours <name of your other branch>
```

There's also the option of falling back to the other branch's conflicted changes with `-Xtheirs`

For more reference, check [git's advanced merging docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#Other-Types-of-Merges)

Comment: Note that `-X ours` (spelled with or without a space) takes "our" *change*, not our *file*. For instance, supposed in file `README`, we changed `color` to `colour` on line 17 while they changed `red` to `green` on the same line. These conflict, so `-X ours` keeps it as `red colour`. Meanwhile they changed line 34 to refer back to the `green dots` ... which we didn't touch, so now line 34 refers to `green dots` even though line 17 says `red colour`.

Comment: @torek You're right, thanks for the correction! I've edited the response to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Try `git merge --abort`

It aborts the current merge and takes you back where you were.