# How to abort merging when conflicts occur in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea with Git. When I pull from repository, I get Merge Conflict error.
On the bottom right of IDEA shows `merging feature/branch-XXX` after the conflicts.
Now I want to **abort** this pull(merge).

I could **reset** the current branch to **clean status**. I could also **abort** the merging with TortoiseGit.
But how can I **abort** the merging conveniently with **IDEA**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

conveniently? Not yet (Sept. 2018), not before 2019.2 (see below)

This is what [issue IDEA-119995](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119995) is for.

> Git: provide possibility to abort merge process

Before 2019.2, you had to switch to the terminal [and type `git merge --abort`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2534968/6309).

---

The related [issue IDEA-122038](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122038) adds in May 2019:

> Cherry-pick now is recognized in the same way as rebase and merge, and indicated in the same way - Branch indicator in the status bar shows Cherry-picking in `<branch>`.
>
> **It is also possible to abort Cherry-pick in the same way - using Abort action in the Branches popup or VCS - Git menu**

So the option to abort should be available since IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.

[image: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-659081?sign=MTU3ODc4NzIwMDAwMHwxMS0xfDc0LTY1OTA4MXw0ZEJuMHBNZnNZRnkxWjc2WlRaZk5SNlJ2VVdjMFF5bGlDMWVmanQ5dHc0PQ==&updated=1557149118930]

This is an image for cherry-pick, but it would apply to merge and rebase as well.