# Git rebase forces merge

Tags: git, github, gitlab, rebase

I am new to the idea of `git rebase`, but I understand the purpose of it. Essentially if you are working on a feature branch `new`, and you want all the changes made to `master` reflected in your local branch, then `git rebase` is the way to go.

So I created my repo, with the general master branch.

I modified the `README.md` file and added one line. I committed and pushed.

Then I created a new branch called `new`.

Here I added two random files `a` and `b`, committed, and pushed.

Now I switched back to my master, and added another line to the `README.md` file. I committed and pushed.

So now, `README.md` on `master` looks like this:

```
line 1 data
line 2 data
```

On `new`, `README.md` looks like this:

```
line 1 data
```

and so in order to get it updated with master's README, I perform `git rebase origin/master` from the `new` branch.

Then git "rewinds" my work, and **puts it on top of** the `line 2 data` commit.

Now if I `vim README.me`, I see the same file as `master`.

What I want to happen now is I continue working on `new`, and nothing of a merge commit arises (image 2). What actually ends up happening is that `git status` says `origin/new have diverged ... you have x and y different commits each ... use git pull`.

I use `git pull`, and then a merge commit appears, which I must later push (image 1).

I don't want this "merge commit" because then the workflow looks like image 1 instead of image 2. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` uses `git merge` under the hood.  If you want it to rebase instead of merging, use `git config --global pull.rebase true`.

Comment: Or `git pull --rebase` for a one shot, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352008/8699120